# Regular Expression seems not to be functioning

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a problem with my string. I don't know what's wrong with it. I just want to make it change color in RTB. Whenever I typed in "accesskey=" or "data-blablabla-blabla=" (without the quotation marks) in my RTB, the code's color is still black.

My Code:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string attributes = @"\b(accesskey=|\data\-.+?\=)\b";
     MatchCollection attributeMatches = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, attributes);

     foreach (Match m in attributeMatches)
     {
         richTextBox1.SelectionStart = m.Index;
         richTextBox1.SelectionLength = m.Length;
         richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: how is this related to strings? Maybe a Regex title would better fit your question

Comment: Are you sure the regex matches anything?

Comment: have you tried to see if the selection works for arbitrary positions without any regex matching? If yes then check your regex.

Comment: @BartoszKP I did. No error found. I think there's something wrong with my string.

Comment: @Hafiz What do you mean by "No error found". The obvious question is whether the `foreach` loop runs at least once. And probably it doesn't. And this suggests what others have said here - it's a problem with your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Regular Expression Language Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `\b` is a backspace character which I seriously doubt you'll find in your text. As a result, your regex will never match anything.

If you want to match against whitespace, use `\s`

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir but it's not working sir. When I try to remove the equal sign in the string, everything works well. That's why I think there's something wrong with my string or maybe I need to add \?

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos! Read the page you've linked. The problem was \b just like what you've said.